# Visual Studio Extension Package - Custom File Type - Editor and Icon

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, vsix

currently I am adding a custom file type (.cft for example) to my Visual Studio project using and instance of the project (EnvDTE.ProjectItem) and the method AddFromFile(".cft").

No my question is how can I tell Visual Studio to use the standard XML editor for all .cft files and possibly how I can assign an Icon for all .cft files (for the Solution Explorer).

Note, I also assign a Custom Tool to the file if this makes a difference using the following code:

```
var vsProjItem = projectItem.Object as VSProjectItem;
pitem.Properties.Item("CustomTool").Value = "MyCustomToolName";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new ItemTemplate with following structure:

```
__TemplateIcon.ico
YourTemplateName.vstemplate [Compile it as vstemplate]
YourFile.cft
```

the following structure should generate you a *.zip file, which can then be placed to Visual Studio templates folder, and later referenced through EnvDTE.

This is the YourTemplateName.vstemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>YourTemplateNameblah</DefaultName>
    <Name>Blahblahblah</Name>
    <Description>BlahBlahBlah</Description>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <ProjectType>?? Your project type ??</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Xml" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cft" ReplaceParameters="true">YourFile.cft</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Quote from MZTOOLS

> The project templates that Visual Studio shows in the New Item dialog
>   are stored in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio \Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache, where they are stored
>   in folders that contain the programming language ("CSharp",
>   "VisualBasic", etc.), technology ("Web", "Cloud", etc.) and locale
>   ("1033", etc.).
>
> The automation model (EnvDTE, EnvDTE80) provides the
>   EnvDTE80.Solution2.GetProjectItemTemplate method to get a project item
>   template file name given the project item template name (such as
>   "Class") and the programming language (such as "CSharp" or
>   "VisualBasic").
>
> Once you have the template file name, you can add a project item to a
>   ProjectItems collection using the AddFromTemplate method. Note: this
>   method returns null (Nothing) rather than the EnvDTE.ProjectItem
>   created, so you may need to locate the created project item in the
>   ProjectItems collection. See PRB: Solution.AddXXX and
>   ProjectItems.AddXXX methods return Nothing (null).

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014009.aspx